# how to get selected index of dropdownbutton in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How to get selectedIndex of dropdown in flutter,

In dropdownbutton there is no property to get selected index, if there how to get the selected index and my code look like this:

```
new DropdownButton( hint:new Text("Select a users"),value: selectedUser,

              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedUser = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: userInfoToMap.map((ListOfUsers value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value.name,
                    child:new Text(value.name,style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                );
              })
                  .toList(),
            ),

          ),),
```

Comment: shouldnt selectedUser be a global variable . When you choose a item, onChange get called?

Comment: can u give me example for that Thanks for the reply

Comment: what about `userInfoToMap.indexOf(newValue)`?

Comment: If I have multiple same elements then it will fails.

Comment: You can wrap them in objects, then each will be different (if the object doesn't have a custom `==` implementation)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should probably use a custom model object (e.g. `User`) as the type for `DropdownButton`.

[image: video]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class User {
  const User(this.name);    
  final String name;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  User selectedUser;
  List<User> users = <User>[User('Foo'), User('Bar')];    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new DropdownButton<User>(
            hint: new Text("Select a user"),
            value: selectedUser,
            onChanged: (User newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedUser = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: users.map((User user) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                value: user,
                child: new Text(
                  user.name,
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we set initial value?

Comment: For future reference, if people are looking for solution. You can set an initial value, by providing a value in `value` argument in `DropdownButton`. You need to make sure your `value` argument matches with the List.

Comment: So how to get the index? I still did not get it.

Comment: To answer your question @KamrulHasanJony, it is a list of a custom object.  This is what I need because I'm using localization and the list is different for different languages.

Answer (score 35):

Similar to Collin Jackson's answer, you can simply use a List of Strings and check the indexOf to set the value, which might be preferable in some situations rather than making a User class.
If you want to set an initial value set _user to an integer value when defined.

```
int _user;
...

var users = <String>[
  'Bob',
  'Allie',
  'Jason',
];

return new DropdownButton<String>(
  hint: new Text('Pickup on every'),
  value: _user == null ? null : users[_user],
  items: users.map((String value) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: new Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _user = users.indexOf(value);
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: This line of code solved my problem 'value: _user == null ? null : users[_user],' thank you :).

Comment: This may not work when we have more than one value with the same String. Assume we have var users = <String>[ 'Bob', 'Bob Martins', 'Allie', 'Jason', 'Jason Derulo']; The approach will be buggy

Comment: When i tried to do the same thing, to get index from dropdownlist items, I get RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: -1.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you selected index of your dropdown

```
userInfoToMap.indexOf(selectedUser);
```