# Flutter: How do I navigate to a new screen using DropDownMenuItems

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to be able to navigate to a new screen when I choose MEN and another screen when I choose WOMEN.
I've tried and did not seem to have any luck. There seems to be nothing on this on the web. 
Please how d I do this?

Here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: new DropdownButton(
        value: null, //Have no idea what to put here
        items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
          new DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text('MEN', style: style),
          ),
          new DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text('WOMEN', style: style),
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: null,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Get the [selected index of dropdownbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323682/how-to-get-selected-index-of-dropdownbutton-in-flutter) and based on that [navigate to a new screen](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add value in DropDownMenuItem as

```
new DropdownMenuItem(
     value: "MEN",
      child: new Text('MEN', style: style),
),
```

Then inside onChanged you should check value and manage navigation.

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: new DropdownButton(
                value: "MEN", //Default value
                items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
                  new DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: "MEN",
                    child: new Text('MEN', style: style),
                  ),
                  new DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: "WOMEN",
                    child: new Text('WOMEN', style: style),
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  Widget widget;
                  if (v == "MEN") {
                    widget = new MenWidget();
                  } else if (v == "WOMEN") {
                    widget = new WomenWidget();
                  }
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widget),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

---

**UPDATE ACCORDING TO COMMENT**

To update body according to selection, you should use StatefulWidget.

```
class DropDownButtonScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DropDownButtonScreenState();
  }
}

class _DropDownButtonScreenState extends State<DropDownButtonScreen> {
  String ddValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ddValue = "MEN";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: new DropdownButton(
            value: ddValue, //Default value
            items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                value: "MEN",
                child: new Text('MEN'),
              ),
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                value: "WOMEN",
                child: new Text('WOMEN'),
              ),
            ],
            onChanged: (v) {
              ddValue = v;
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: getBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    if (ddValue == "MEN") {
      return Center(child: Text("Widget for men"));
    } else if (ddValue == "WOMEN") {
      return Center(child: Text("Widget for Women"));
    }
    return Center(child: Text("Widget not found"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But rather than navigating to a new screen, I tried displaying the new widget in the Scaffold's body. When i tried doing this, the value on the DropdownButton did not change to thre selected value neither did the widget passed to the body display. How do I solve this?

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked! I did the same thing but what I did wrong was at the if statement I did not 'return' the new Men or Women widget.